# What does [python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"] do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I installed tensorflow, following the steps in their official site. But, in the site, as the last step of installation, they have given a line of code to "Verify the install". But they have not told what this code would give as the output.

The line is:

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

When I typed in this code, I got the following as the output:

```
C:\Users\joelj\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\joelj\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\joelj\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\joelj\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\joelj\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\joelj\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
C:\Users\joelj\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\joelj\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\joelj\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\joelj\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\joelj\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\joelj\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
Tensor("Sum:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

How do I know that the installation is complete, and what does this Output mean?

Comment: You don't have to show us the entire error message. Try to only show us the important errors. It will make it a lot cleaner and easier to read

Answer (score 4):

It's just a warning, not an error. You need to downgrade numpy to version `1.16.4` to make it compatible with the your current version of tensorflow. Your installation is completed.

Check the output at the end: `Tensor("Sum:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)`

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

Above is a way of running python code using terminal (`-c` is command argument).

In this code, you are first importing tensorflow library given by `import tensorflow as tf`.

`tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])` outputs a tensor of the shape `[1000, 1000]` filled with random normal values. It outputs random values from a normal distribution.

`tf.reduce_sum` computes the sum of elements across dimensions of a tensor. If axis is `None`, all dimensions are reduced, and a tensor with a single element is returned.

Since, you are printing the result without creating a session, that's why you are getting output as `Tensor("Sum:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)`. Read about tf.Session() from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session).

In order to print the actual result run below command:

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; sess=tf.Session(); print(sess.run(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000]))))"
```

Comment: Upgrading numpy is not going to stop the warnings, it's a newer version of numpy that is printing them. To get rid of the warnings with the current version of tensorflow, you need to downgrade to version 1.16.4 See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31249

Answer (score 1):

The command is to call python to execute what's after `-c`.
You can see `FutureWarning` in the output lines and it's caused by [numpy](https://numpy.org/) version updating in the future. And you can ignore them or set in python to make them not output anymore.
The real output is the **last line**. And the installation is **completed**.

Answer (score 0):

pip install "numpy<1.17"
Is resolve the problem.